# NT4 domain: Obtain a list of users, computers and their last logins

Tags: windows

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up Auditing for the log on and log off. Also refer the below URLs

http://www.rlmueller.net/Logon5.htm

http://www.petri.co.il/list_all_users_and_groups_in_domain.htm

Comment: I used NET USER and to get the information. Some regular expression text mangling and I have myself a spreadsheet. Much obliged!